# Conditional formatting + copy to other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I don't have experience with conditional formatting and I would need some help in regards to this. I have to write a formula which states that if:

- any cell from column A equals **Test** i.e. A2 = Test and
- any cell from column B equals **Support** i.e. B2 = Support Then
- column C i.e. C2 must turn **red**. If a value is inserted in C2, then the cell must turn **white**.

Thanks for your help and time!

My code:

```
Sub testcells (z As Long)

If Cells(z, "A") = "Test" And Cells(z, "B") = "Support"  Then
Cells(z, "c").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
ElseIf Cells(z, "A") = "Test 1" And Cells(z, "B") = "Support"   Then
Cells(z, "c").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
ElseIf Cells(z, "A") = "Test 2" And Cells(z, "B") = "Support" Then
Cells(z, "c").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Else
Cells(z, "c").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried to get this to work? [ask]

Comment: You don't need VBA code. Conditional Formatting formula will work. Something like this for the formula: `AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C2)),OR(COUNTIF(A:A,"Test"),COUNTIF(B:B,"Support"))`

Comment: done. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my excel, this worked:

`=IF(AND(A2="test";B2="Support";ISBLANK(C2)=TRUE);TRUE;FALSE)`

you don't need VBA at all.